# How to create a widget on android that can open other apps

Tags: android

I am trying to make a widget that acts like a container for a group of apps. So when the widget is pressed it opens a view showing all the apps assigned to it. From here any of the apps can be started. This widget will be placed on the home screen. Is this achievable on android? If so, how? Please help!
Thanks

Comment: [How to create a widget](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/)
and [How to start another application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know if there is an existing apt that can also accomplish this task?